# Why can't SVN checkout into a virtualbox shared folder?

Tags: svn, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to checkout into the virtualbox shared folder with svn 1.7 in ubuntu 12.04 running as a guest on a windows 7 host. I had read that this error was a 1.6 problem, and updated - but am still receiving the error:

svn: E000071: Can't move '/mnt/hostShare/code/www/.svn/tmp/svn-hsOG5X' to '/mnt/hostShare/code/www/trunk/statement.aspx?d=201108': Protocol error

I found this [blog post](http://blog.arc90.com/2008/07/02/fixing-the-cant-move-svntmpentries-to-svnentries-error/) about the same error in a mac environment, but am finding that changing the folder/file permissions does nothing.

vim .svn/entires just has the number 12 - does this need to be changed?

Thank you for any assistance!

(just another reason for why I prefer git...)

Comment: I have also tried creating a symlink to the repo (which I can checkout into other folders.) but am running into the read-only file system error. Which, is not fixed by issuing VBoxManage setextradata ubuntu VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/hostShare 1

Comment: Now when I try to create a symlink it throws 'protocol error' instead of read-only file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a question mark in the filename to which you are trying to move the file.
That is not a legal character in a file on NTFS file-systems.

Generally I found the shared folder function of VirtualBox unreliable and after trying multiple times I always went with a standard Windows network share - which might also not help in your case though.